# notations in the Wilks' famous paper

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I'm reading  [the famous paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177732360) where Wilks' theorem was first introduced. In the last sentence of the first paragraph, the author says that

> A set $\omega$ of simple hypotheses is specified by taking all simple hypotheses of the set $\Omega$ for which $\theta_i = \theta_{0i}, i = m+1, m+2, ... , h$.

However, the variables $\theta_{0i}$ and $m$ have not been defined in the paper. How can we interpret those?

Comment: The $\theta_i$ are the parameters, as defined earlier in that paragraph, and therefore the $\theta_{0i}$ are the "specified values," also referred to earlier in the paragraph.  There's no need to define $m$ because its meaning is clearly established by its usage.

Comment: @whuber Is $\left[ m+1, m+2, ... , h \right] $ a subset of $\left[ 1, 2, 3, ... h \right] $ for any $m<h$ ?

Comment: In the context, it *must* be a subset, because these values are indexing the parameters.  And this establishes that $m$ *must* be a non-negative integer.  (When $m\ge h,$ the subset is empty.)

Answer (score 0):

It's just a single, fixed value. It's in the definition of a "simple" hypothesis. Contrast with a composite hypothesis where we might write $\theta_i \le \theta_{01}$. We don't need, or care, to know what $\theta_{01}$ is.